# Design ZKP to satisfy x1*x2(mod n)=x3 from(Pallier encryptions)

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, zero-knowledge

I have 3 Pailler encryption p1=E(x1;r1),p2=E(x2;r2);p3=E(x3;r3) such that
x1*x2(mod n)=x3. P(Prover) knows (x1,r1);(x2,r2);(x3,r3).

Can I design a ZKP(interactive & non-interactive) for P to convince V(verifier) that values hidden by p1,p2,p3 satisfy x1*x2(mod n)=x3.